# php pdo lastInsertId() as input to second table

Tags: php, pdo

I appreciate all the help!!  I am new to PDO and am having an issue when I perform inserts to 2 different tables.  I have a field in the second table (fk_employee) that I want the last recorded id from the first query(insert).  When I run the queries I receive the following error:

`Query failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'TN', '77777', ' at line 10`

Here is my method:

```
        function completeCallback()
    {
        // finally, all form data is valid and the user has confirmed they
        // want to proceed. Now we do all the final processing here.

        $name_title = $this->getValue('name_title');
        $emp_lastname = $this->getValue('emp_lastname');
        $emp_suffix = $this->getValue('emp_suffix');
        $emp_firstname = $this->getValue('emp_firstname');
        $emp_middlename = $this->getValue('emp_middlename');
        $emp_prefername = $this->getValue('emp_prefername');
        $address1 = $this->getValue('address1');
        $address2 = $this->getValue('address2');
        $city = $this->getValue('city');
        $state = $this->getValue('state');
        $postal_code = $this->getValue('postal_code');
        $country = $this->getValue('country');

      $conn = parent::connect();
      $sql = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_EMPLOYEES . " (
                name_title,
                emp_lastname,
                emp_firstname,
                emp_suffix,
                emp_prefername,
                emp_middlename
              ) VALUES (
                :name_title,
                :emp_lastname,
                :emp_firstname,
                :emp_suffix,
                :emp_prefername,
                :emp_middlename
              )";

      try {
        $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        $st->bindValue( ":name_title", $name_title, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":emp_lastname", $emp_lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":emp_firstname", $emp_firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":emp_suffix", $emp_suffix, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":emp_prefername", $emp_prefername, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":emp_middlename", $emp_middlename, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        if($st->execute()){
            $lastInsertID = $conn->lastInsertId();
        }
      $sql = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_EMPLOYEEADD . " (
                fk_employee,
                address1,
                address2,
                city,
                state,
                postal_code,
                country
              ) VALUES (
                :fk_employee;
                :address1,
                :address2,
                :city,
                :state,
                :postal_code,
                :country
              )";

        $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        $st->bindValue( ':fk_employee', $lastInsertID, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $st->bindValue( ':address1', $address1, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ':address2', $address2, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ':state', $state, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ':postal_code', $postal_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        if($st->execute()){
            $lastInsertID = $conn->lastInsertId();
        }
      } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        parent::disconnect( $conn );
        die( "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
      }
    }
```

Here is my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ds_employee` (
  `id_employee` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_title` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `emp_suffix` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `emp_prefername` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `emp_middlename` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employee`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

Table #2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ds_employee_address` (
  `id_employee_address` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_employee` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address2` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `postal_code` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employee_address`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_employee` (`fk_employee`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

I am sure it something simple but I have been banging my head and can't figure it out!!

Thanks,
REF

Comment: Unrelated: does fk_employee suggests what I think it does?

Answer (score 0):

Change that query as bellow.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_EMPLOYEEADD . " (
                fk_employee,
                address1,
                address2,
                city,
                state,
                postal_code,
                country
              ) VALUES (
                :fk_employee,
                :address1,
                :address2,
                :city,
                :state,
                :postal_code,
                :country
              )";
```

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you with such a stupid question!!  Thank you very much.  That was it!!